# abstract states and multiple views in angular 2

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular, router, ionic2

I'd like to migrate a little prototype *from* Ionic 1.1.1 with Angular 1.4.7 *to* Ionic 2 with Angular 2.0.0-beta.1. In my current prototype I use the Angular `ui-router` with abstract states and nested views.

Here's the view `mystate.html`:

```
...
<ion-content scroll="false" class="mainPage">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-33">
            <ion-nav-view name="left"></ion-nav-view>
        </div>      
        <div class="col col-67">
            <ion-nav-view name="right"></ion-nav-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
...
```

Here are the defined states:

```
...
.state('mystate', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/ordering/views/mystate.html',
    url:'/ordering'
})
.state('mystate.home', {
    cache: false,
    url:'/home',
    views: {
        'left': {
            templateUrl: 'app/mystate/views/leftviewHome.html'
        },
        'right': {
            templateUrl: 'app/mystate/views/rightviewHome.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('mystate.leftA', {
    url:'/leftA',
    views: {
        'left': {
            templateUrl: 'app/mystate/views/leftViewA.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('mystate.rightA', {
    url:'/rightA,
    views: {
        'right': {
            templateUrl: 'app/mystate/views/rightViewA.html'
        }
    }
})
...
```

The Angular `ui-router` allows the following:

- Load two different templates at once (e.g. `mystate.home`).
- Load nested views independently from each other (e.g `mystate.leftA` and  `mystate.rightA`).

So I have no clue how to achieve this with the Angular2 router. Can someone give me an example or a hint on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with ionic2 but it doesn't require you to use angular2's router, which is still under heavy development.

Essentially, it's as easy as adding two `ion-nav` components and setting their roots.

```
<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-card style="height: 200px;">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-nav [root]="detail1"></ion-nav>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card style="height: 200px;">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-nav [root]="detail2"></ion-nav>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

And in your main components ts file.

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {Detail1Page} from '../detail-1/detail-1';
import {Detail2Page} from '../detail-2/detail-2';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  detail1 = Detail1Page;
  detail2 = Detail2Page;
  constructor() { }
}
```